# Querying by id in Firestore Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Currently, as far as I know, there is no command-line interface for querying Firestore. The only way to query our documents is to do it through our own program, or through Firestore console. In the console, the only way to query a document by its id is to use the browser "Find" feature. However, when the number of documents in a collection increases above a threshold, which I don't know, Google Chrome cannot find the id. It's very inconvenient to scroll through the list of documents and use the find function of the browser again and again to find the id.

Please advise a more efficient way or implement a more efficient way to query documents by id in Firestore Console.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

While you can't filter a collection by a document ID, you **can** find a document with a specific ID by entering it in the little address bar/breadcrumb trail that sits above your data structure in the console.

Steps:

1. Select the collection that the document is in
2. Hover over the breadcrumb trail at the top and click on the pencil icon

   [image]
3. Enter a `/` and then the ID of the document

   [image]
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The console will now load the document with the ID you entered.

Comment: Very helpful! The hover appearing pencil edit icon does not help at all for the users to see and figure out that they can edit the path to a specific document, it should have been there always on not only on hover!