# Firestore: find element by id from Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an user from my app in Firebase:
[image]

and with it I also created some elements that I store in Firestore:

[image]

So as you can see, that elements is linked to this new user

If I go to Firestore db, all this elements are created ok but I don't know how to search by id, only by fields that I created for that user (email, name, etc):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Document ID for *user* collection should match the UID that Firebase Authentication gives to you. Instead, you are letting Firestore to automatically generate the document ID.

Comment: I know, that's the same ID (1st image on the right) but what I mean is that I don't know how to search for it in Firestore. I can only use those suggested fields (last image)

Comment: I think you mean that you can't query by the uid. If that's the case, add an uid field to your document.

Comment: I don't want to modify any of my documents, I just need to filter by id from that UI. Isn't that possible without updating it? I have thousands of documents and just need to find a single one

Comment: Hi @Dani, Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266223/querying-by-id-in-firestore-console) answers your question?

Comment: I didn't know you could modify that path. That worked like a charm. Feel free to add an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Franks' answer, you can find a document/element with a specific ID by entering it in the little address bar/breadcrumb trail that sits above the data structure in the console. **Pencil icon** on the breadcrumbs are hidden by default, hover on the breadcrumbs for it to appear. By clicking on it, address bar will be shown. Enter a `/` and then the ID of the document/element.

For more detailed information, you can refer to this **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266223/querying-by-id-in-firestore-console)**.