# How to find a doc by uid in the firestore web UI / console

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If I know the uid of a firestore doc, how do I find the doc in the web UI?

In code, I can do something like `db.collection('users').doc(uid)`, but in the web UI I don't know what to do.

Comment: Use the filters (triangles on top of each collection).  You can enter the id you want there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: find element by id from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919565/firestore-find-element-by-id-from-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pencil button (only appears on hover):

[image]